# How do I get a boxed value out?

Tags: rust

I am seeing an issue with a boxed value and I don't know how to fix this.

```
pub struct BinaryTree<T> {
    root: Option<T>,
    left: Option<Box<BinaryTree<T>>>,
    right: Option<Box<BinaryTree<T>>>,
}

impl<T> BinaryTree<T> {
    fn tree_height(&self) -> i32 {
        match &self {
            BinaryTree {
                root: None,
                left: None,
                right: None
            } => -1,

            BinaryTree {
                root: Some(_),
                left: None,
                right: None
            } => 0,

            BinaryTree { root: Some(_), left: l, right: r } => {
                let left_height = BinaryTree::tree_height(l);
                let right_height = BinaryTree::tree_height(r);
                1 + max(left_height, right_height)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The compilation error with the line `let left_height = BinaryTree::tree_height(l);` is this:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/trees/tree.rs:55:59
   |
55 |                 let left_height = BinaryTree::tree_height(l);
   |                                   ----------------------- ^ expected `&BinaryTree<_>`, found `&Option<Box<BinaryTree<T>>>`
   |                                   |
   |                                   arguments to this function are incorrect
   |
   = note: expected reference `&BinaryTree<_>`
              found reference `&Option<Box<BinaryTree<T>>>`
```

How can we fix this?

Comment: First things first, `l` and `r` are `Option`s so you may not have a boxed value at all. You'll need to handle the case where either are `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rust
BinaryTree { root: Some(_), left: l, right: r }
```

means that `left` and `right` are just renamed as `l` and `r` respectively, there is no pattern matching, therefore their type is `Option<Box<_>>`, not `Box<_>`, if you want to handle the case where `left` and `right` are not `None`, you have to write it like this:

```rust
BinaryTree { root: Some(_), left: Some(l), right: Some(r) }
```

If you make that change, the code will still not compile, since there will be unmatched cases (where only one of them is `Some`, or when `root` is `None` while `left` or `right` is `Some`)

Comment: Thank you. I updated the pattern and `tree_height` function to add the rest of the missing patterns.

Can we modify the struct definition in such a way that, when `root` is `None`, `left` and `right` also have to be `None` ?

Comment: @ancoraimparo To describe that kind of structure to the compiler, you'd have to make the whole type a custom `enum` like `enum BinaryTree { Rootless, Rooted { root: T, left: Option<_>, right: Option<_> } }` or something similar.

Comment: @kmdreko, isn't that just `Option<BinaryTree>` with `root: T`?

Comment: @cafce25 it is! :) I'm guessing OP has `root` as an `Option` to express an empty `BinaryTree`, and if so I would suggest transitioning to a `BinaryTree { root: Option<Node> }` structure where `Node` has `root: T` and optional left and right instead.